# How to print on half page or A5 using AirPrint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, airprint

I have an app that needs to print receipts and passes from the iPad. I have implemented the AirPrint SDK which is working fine, i.e., I am able to print documents from the iPad using an AirPrint compatible printer.

The issue is I need these receipts and passes to be on half a page (half of an A4 page that is) or an A5 page. No matter what changes I make to the print job, it always prints in the full A4 page and in landscape.

Here's my code to print:

```
UIPrintInteractionController *printer = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
UIPrintInfo *printObject = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
[printObject setJobName:@"Receipt"];
[printObject setOutputType:UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral];
[printObject setOrientation:UIPrintInfoOrientationLandscape];

UIPrintFormatter *printFormatter = [[UIPrintFormatter alloc] init];
[printFormatter setContentInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

[printer setPrintFormatter:printFormatter];
[printer setPrintInfo:printObject];
[printer setDelegate:self];
[printer setPrintingItem:targetURL];
[printer presentFromRect:sender inView:view animated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController,BOOL completed, NSError *error){}];
```

I also tried implementing the `choosePaper` delegate method but it didn't help either. Oh and while creating the document, I specify the size:

```
CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(595, 420);
NSString* fileName = @"GatePass.PDF";

NSArray *arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);
```

The way it should ideally work is that if the user uses A5 paper in a print, print normally. If the user uses A4 paper, print in just half the page and so on.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Do you have idea how to done this now? Can you let me know if you did because I was also looking for printing receipt in A5, but not much answer I can get

Answer (score 1):

Use the chosePaper delegate method. If A5 is listed in the list you are given then pick that paper. If the printer has A5 and knows it has A5 then you should get A5 output. You'll also want to create the PDF at the size returned from chosePaper.

You can test this with the printer simulator. Use the load paper size button to setup one of the printers with "Simulate Paper sensors" and with A5 loaded in one of the trays.